# Linking freetype with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, dynamic-linking, freetype

I'm having troubles with linking `freetype 2` under linux using `cmake` when building a C++11 project with an `extern C` library.

With cmake and freetype 2 I basically have 2 options :

- use the utility `freetype-config` like `freetype-config --libs`
- use the `FindFreetype` [cmake module](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_2.6.0_Docs)

Now I'm trying to implement the second option and I'm not very skilled with `cmake` nor I understand the logic of it.

My problem is the linking phase, I have no idea how to do that properly plus this module is not as complete as the result of `freetype-config --libs` which really includes all the libraries and flags that I need, and not just the path of a file; so I'm assuming that I have to do the same for `zlib` and `libpng`.

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (FreetypeTutorials1)

include(FindFreetype)
include_directories(${FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS})

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O2 -std=c++11")

SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-v -lfreetype")

add_executable( demo "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp")
```

`./src/main.cpp` ( just some random code so I have something to feed to the compiler )

```
extern "C" {
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
}
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  FT_Library library;
  auto error = FT_Init_FreeType(&library);
  if (error)
  {
    std::cout << "An error !\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To load a module like `FindFreetype.cmake` you need to use it in cmake with the `find_package`-command. The first argument is the package name. The "Find" of its corresponding filename is added automatically by cmake.

While `include` might work with `find_package` you can add some flags. For example, as shown below, `REQUIRED`, to make cmake fail when freetype wasn't found.

Additionally linking with cmake should be done with the command `target_link_libraries`.

This is how I would write you CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (FreetypeTutorials1)

find_package(Freetype REQUIRED)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O2 -std=c++11")

SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-v")

add_executable( demo src/main.cpp) # CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR is implicit here
target_link_libraries(demo ${FREETYPE_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(demo PRIVATE ${FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

`target_link_libraries` is platform independent whereas `'-lfreetype` in `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` is not.

The CMakeLists.txt will work on other platforms where freetype is available.

(Edit 2019: use `target_include_directories()` instead of `include_directories()`

Comment: I need a complete example because this is my first time with this.

Comment: so using the `include(FindFreetype)` is wrong ? I also found out that `target_link_libraries(demo freetype)` works as well, there are any differences ?

Comment: so the difference is that if `include` fails there will be no message or interruption, and `include` is a really generic command. `find_package` is a more specific macro with more control and options. But the result in both cases is the inclusion of the package that I want ? I mean if you set aside the "controls" and the business logic for a minute, the effect is the same ?

Comment: Use `target_include_directories` with modern CMake (3.0+) to avoid polluting other projects with global flags.